# Parallel performing several tasks

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, winrt-async

- **NOTE: This is for winrt Universal app** *

I'm fetching data from a service through use of an async method:

```
var activityList = await Task.Run(() => dataService.GetActivitiesAsync());
```

But for each activity I still need to load Athlete data.
So now I just loop the activities and load up the athlete data like so ( there is no bulk load option for athlete ):

```
foreach(var activity in activityList)
{
    activity.Athlete = dataService.GetAthleteAsync(activity.AthleteID);
}
```

But this GetAthleteAsync will also return a Task, so I was just wondering isn't there a better way to get this done in a background thread? Somehow with Task.WhenAll or anything else?
The Athlete property on the Activity object has NotifyPropertyChanged so the UI will show the needed data when it's set.
The GetAthleteAsync method will already try to cache athletes based on the given id.

Any suggestions on how to make this perform better?

Some details, all methods are connecting to a web API.
Mostly we'll be targetting 10 unique Athletes ( but depending on the user, this could increase ).

Comment: Is `GetAthlete` method so heavy to make it asynchronous? In fact, behind that question, there is the question of, from where do you fetch the data? A database? A Website? RAM?

If it is database, group the `GetAthlete` queries into one query, it will be much more efficient, if it is from RAM, there is no need for making `GetAthlete` async, and if it is from website, then, using `Parallel.ForEach` may help.

Comment: I'll add more details to the question...

Comment: What about Parallel.Foreach()? Activities will be split into multiple subcollections and their iteration will be planned to ThreadPool. And every Athlete data can be obtained synchronously.

Comment: I don't think Parallel.ForEach is available on winrt universal. But I can be wrong.

Comment: @Depechie `Platforms - Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Windows 8.1` http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Guillaume ha well spotted... so how could we change the given code to match that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hms, if `dataService.GetActivitiesAsync()` is async and everything is called from the UI-thread, what you can do is this:

```
// no wrapping in Task, it is async
var activityList = await dataService.GetActivitiesAsync();

// Select a good enough tuple
var results = (from activity in activityList
               select new { 
                Activity = activity, 
                AthleteTask = dataService.GetAthleteAsync(activity.AthleteID)
               }).ToList(); // begin enumeration

// Wait for them to finish, ie relinquish control of the thread
await Task.WhenAll(results.Select(t => t.AthleteTask));

// Set the athletes
foreach(var pair in results)
{
  pair.Activity.Athlete = pair.AthleteTask.Result;
}
```

(Written of the top of my head, ie no syntax checking, so some method calls could be wrong)

Comment: You block the UI during the call with Task.AwaitAll, don't you?

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(results.Select(t => t.AthleteTask));`

Comment: @CédricBignon Indeed, mistake on my part, `WhenAll` is the correct method.

Comment: I'll need to check the code when I'm on my dev pc again :)

Comment: Ok, this works!! But now I'm stuck with how to best implement caching for this... Because all tasks are triggered parallel now, it seems that my ConcurrentDictionary is not 'hit' when all task fire and start. In other words now I'm going online several times for the same Athlete id.

Comment: Could you give a code example? Maybe open a new question if it is much broader than the scope of this question?

Comment: Hmm maybe a new Q is relevant indeed. But the problem is that the method GetAthleteAsync() has a check first concurrentDict.ContainsKey(AthleteID) so to return the athlete from mem instead of going online. Now when all tasks start at almost same time parallel the dictionary is empty for each task

Comment: @Depechie: That should be a followup question. The new question is about async caching. In the new Q, post the current `GetAthleteAsync` method (at least the part that uses the cache).

Comment: Will post a new one :) @StephenCleary